# projective resolution for an $I$-torsion $R$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with non-zero identity, $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $M$ be an $I$-torsion $R$-module.
We know that there exists an injective resolution of $M$ in which each term is an
$I$-torsion $R$-module.
Is true this result for projective resolutions? 
Is there a projective resolution of $M$ in which each term is an
$I$-torsion $R$-module?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just take a free resolution of $M$ as a $R/I$-module ?

Comment: How so? Projective modules are direct summands into free modules which are well known to be torsion-free.

Comment: The OP should at least try to do this with $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=R/2R$...